# Async invoke ws-addressing in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is it possible make async invoke a web service with callback?
i saw in 4.2 new feature barrier, may be with this and inbound-gateway + outbound-gateway we could make async. Please help.

Comment: Would be better if you share with us some samples on the matter and your PoC where you are with the solution right now. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that `async ws-addressing`. So, I'd be glad to help you and address something in the Spring Integration as a new feature, but I need to have some hook to tie. Thanks for the patience!